# Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, then $[a\cdot b]\ge [a]\cdot [b]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I want a proof verification of the the statement in the question. I struggled alot with this one so I hope something is correct.

In this situation $[x]$ denotes "the greatest integer in x", where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We have that the fractional part of $x$ is $\{x\}=x-[x]\in [0,1)$. Consider $[a\cdot b]-[a]\cdot [b]$.

$$[a\cdot b]-[a]\cdot [b]=\bigl[ (\{a\}+[a])\cdot (\{b\}\cdot [b]) \bigr] -[a]\cdot [b]= \bigl[\{a\}\{b\}+\{a\}[b]+\{b\}[a]+[a][b]\bigr]-[a][b]= \\ [a][b]+\bigl[\{a\}\{b\}+\{a\}[b]+\{b\}[a] \bigr]-[a][b]=\bigl[\{a\}\{b\}+\{a\}[b]+\{b\}[a] \bigr] \ge [0]=0.$$ In summary $$[a\cdot b]-[a]\cdot [b] \ge 0\Leftrightarrow [a\cdot b]\ge [a]\cdot [b].$$

Comment: It is correct according to me

Comment: It's correct. Alternatively you could do: $ab \ge [a]\cdot [b] \implies [ab]\ge [a]\cdot[b]$ since the RHS is an integer.